# Python, fix dates using regex

Tags: regex, python-3.x

I have a column of "dates" in excel collected by different people over years and **I want to create a proper dates columns in Pandas dataframe out of that "dirty" one, with start date and end date columns.** This dirty column is full of rubbish and sentences and it is tricky to get the day/month/year out of it. I managed to clean it slightly but still I am long way from the end. This is an example of dirty dates column looks like:

```
['Apr 1 - 10 2012', 'Aug 6 - sept 17 2018', 'Jan 2017 (explosion) - dec 
 31', 'April 15 - Nov 20', "Mar 1 - Jun 30 '12", "Sep 27 - Nov 30, 
 2012", "Dec 7, 2015 - Feb 15, '16", "June 21 2016 - June 27, 2016",
 "July 6 - 13 (est), 2016", "Mar 28 2016 - dec 31 2017", 
 "Nov 30, 2016 - Aug 31, 2016", "1 oct - 15 oct 2017",
 "March 26 to May 3, 2017", "Jan 4,2018", 
 "Jan 26, 2017 - end of march 2018", 
 "5 days assumed for Sep '11, 
 "Sep 15 - Oct 12 '11 (abc 50 n/g) something in 2015 but something 
  else happened '16", 
 "Mar 17 - Apr 15, '12 (assumed 1 mo.)", 
 "Jan 1 - 31 '12 a/b due to many words here and descriptions."]
```

I have more than 30 000 rows. 
For start date I tried first splitting them by '-' because they all seem to have either 'to' or '-' and doing the following but that didn't give great results, I can't cover all of the cases mentioned above.

```
def start_date(row):
    row_start = ''
    num_words = len(str(row).split(' '))
    # trying to skip long rows with many words but I don't think this is the way to go
    if (row is not None) and (type(row) != float) and (type(row) is not datetime.datetime) and (num_words <= 7) and (("'" in row) or ("\"" in row)):
       row = row.replace('"', "'")
       row = row.replace('!', "1")
       row = row.replace("`", "")
       row = row.replace("' ", "'")
       row = row.replace(", ", " ")
       year_start = re.search(r"""(?<=\')(\d\d)""", row)[0]
       row = row.replace('to', '-')

       row_start = row.split('-')[0]
       row_start = row_start.replace(' \"', ',')
       row_start = row_start.replace(" \'", ',')
       row_start = row_start.replace(",,", ',')
       row_start = str(row_start).strip()

return str(row_start) + ', 20' + str(year_start)
```

Any help is appreciated.

If anyone knows a proper regex how to cover only the edge cases above that would help a lot too.

Comment: The inconsistent format in your file is going to make it almost impossible to write a function to parse the dates without hundreds of edge cases. I suggest you manually change them to a standard format first.

Comment: I was hoping to find another solution because I am not sure how to change > 30 000 rows in excel that are messy like that. It will probably take me the same amount of time?

Comment: If you don't know all the formats of the rows then there's no way around it. You could find a row without numbers for example: `December fourth`. For a start, you should at least figure out how many different cases there are

Comment: There's no way you're going to cover all cases with a single regex. Do it in stages - fix a few cases that you can easily match, then a few more that you can match with a different regex, and repeat until all of the data is cleaned up. Otherwise, find a solution other than regex.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. It feels impossible to determine how many different cases there are. I will try to keep splitting them and see if I can save as much as I can.

Comment: It's not impossible. Probably 80-90% are going to be captured by 10-20 lines of code. Then it's an uphill battle where at some point you will probably decide that the remaining effort is in no way commensurate with the added value of getting from, say, 99.999% to 100.00%.  Probably a human reviewer won't be able to firmly establish what the last few ones actually mean, either.